# Windows C: drive apparently nearly empty but cannot account for the used storage

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, windows-11, disk-space

If I go to 'This PC', it says I have 22GB free out of 933GB, which is worrying.

However if I go into the C: drive, select all folders and files (including hidden ones) > right-click > Properties, the total comes to 428GB.

So, there is almost 500GB of space apparently in use, but unaccounted for. What can I do? I've run virus scans, and CCleaner, and optimised the disk (which is an SSD).

How can I find the missing 500GB? Is it possible that Windows is wrong about only 22GB remaining?

Any advice is very much appreciated!

Comment: The approach you’re using to determine your storage use is flawed. Run [WizTree](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows) as an Administrator and provide a screenshot of the disk usage.  “How can I find the missing 500GB? Is it possible that Windows is wrong about only 22GB remaining?” - No

Comment: The OP should be made aware of the `WinSxS` folder and functionality. This "magic" folder shouldn't be touched and it also tends to double-count files leading to an inflated reported size, which is normal. I think 5-15GB would be the expected reported size.

Comment: Check what your [disk management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00QeH.png) tells you.

Comment: Try settings > type 'storage' > select 'delete temporary files' .. Select 'Other' and see if you can determine space hogs ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't sum up the used space on the system disk `C:`.
This disk has areas allocated by the operating system that are
not visible for user utilities.

You should believe the numbers given by File Explorer.
If still in doubt, run an elevated `chkdsk C:` to ensure
that no space is lost, and if it finds no errors then compare
its numbers with those of File Explorer.

To reduce Windows usage of the disk, you can:

- Run any of the suggested folders-tree utilities to find
  wasted space in your own folders
- [Turn off hibernation](https://www.diskpart.com/free-up-space/how-to-delete-hibernation-file-windows-10-3690.html)
  and ensure that `C:\hiberfil.sys` is removed
  (needs Explorer option to view system files)
- Ensure that you don't have the folder `C:\Windows.old`
- [Reduce the Paging File](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/manage-virtual-memory-paging-file-in-windows-11.8618/)
- [Resize ShadowStorage using Vssadmin](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/vssadmin-resize-shadowstorage)

Comment: As long as utilities are run with elevated privileges, they are perfectly capable of capturing the true picture of space usage.

Comment: @Basilevs: Try it and see - the number you get will be less than the used space in File Explorer or `chkdsk`.

Comment: I used Windirstat extensively, and it shows proper size if elevated.

Comment: @Basilevs: For example, on my computer elevated Windirstat gives for `C:` a total of 373 GB, while Explorer used space is 0.39 TB which is 399 GB.

Comment: @Basilevs: I have seen it not work. Volume Shadow Copy hides from everything.

Comment: @harrymc: Explorer is bugged. It counts hard linked files twice. You have them under C:\Windows because Windows uses them internally.

Comment: @Joshua: `chkdsk` is not bugged, and it gives very similar numbers. Note that when a file is written, the space is deducted from the used space. However, this space is only visible in the file-table when the file is closed or flushed by the application. Windirstat goes by the file-table, so can't detect files that are still open and being written.

Comment: "This disk has areas allocated by the operating system that are not visible for user utilities." ??? Why wouldn't they fix this bug?

Comment: Thanks. After a chkdsk it suddenly found over 100GB, so that was a relief!

Answer (score 5):

Try using a disk/file scanning program to analyze the disk's usage.  These programs look at all the files on a disk and lets you visualize what is taking up all the space.  It even categorizes the files for you.

If you arent sure what something is, I wouldnt delete it until you are sure its not something needed.

Here are some programs that can do that:
https://www.makeuseof.com/windirstat-alternatives/

Comment: Note that some of these might need to be run as admininstrator to see every directory.

Answer (score 5):

System files are not always shown, even when show hidden files is selected.

First, try running **Windows Disk Cleanup**. It will remove a lot of unneeded and hidden system files and backups.

After that finishes, try the **TreeSize app**. It will scan your drives and tell you exactly how much space is being allocated where.

Comment: I would generalize this to - directories user has no access to are not included in size computation. The only way to compute true size of a directory is to run a program with elevated privileges.