# A an inexplicable difference between the sum size of files on Local Disk C and its Used space attribute

Tags: filesystems, windows-11, disk-space

I am cleaning my old laptop running Windows 11 Pro. I noticed a detail which does not make sense to me, hence my inquiry.

When select all top-level files in Local Disk C and right-click, then click Properties, I get the reported sum size of 48.7 GB.

[image]

But when I view Properties of Local Disk C directly, I get the reported disk usage of 73.7 GB.

[image]

I would like to understand why this happens, and more importantly, get the additional 24.6 GB of space, if that is possible. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Better duplicate [here](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows/407971#407971)