# How can I clean up junk files from my computer?

Tags: windows, cleaning

I'm getting a new laptop, and giving mine to a co-worker. How can I clean out all the junk & temp files?

(A clean Windows install is not an option.)

Comment: @rm, you might find/add some more answers at http://superuser.com/questions/8141/reclaiming-disk-space-on-windows; Additionally, since you are giving away your laptop, hopefully you have `erased` all sensitive data (passwords/caches/registry-information) that you want to protect (or, maybe you trust the co-worker with all that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new user account and delete the old one, that should take care of a lot of clutter/rubbish.

If it doesn't delete the folder from Documents & Settings, deleting the account will at least mean you can safely delete it.

Then let [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com) delete EVERYTHING (just tick every box in the settings) and defrag the system when it's done.

Answer (score 6):

Try [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/) to remove alot of the common junk. It will remove non-essential files (such as browsing history and temp files) from:

- Internet Explorer
- Firefox
- Google Chrome
- Opera
- Safari
- Windows

  - Recycle Bin
  - Recent Documents
  - Temporary files
  - Log files.
  - Registry
- Many other third-party applications

I understand you do not wish to reinstall Windows, but take a look at my [Erasing data before selling a computer](https://superuser.com/questions/4678/erasing-data-before-selling-a-computer) question which covers a similar topic, especially this answer by [ChrisF](https://superuser.com/users/289/chrisf):

> As a side note on scenarios when you cannot always format and wipe the disk and have to relinquish ownership of a computer with OS intact (like resigning a job and returning the laptop), Scott Hanselman has noted down a checklist on activities to carry out before giving it up forever.
>
> [The Developer's Quitting Your Job Technology Checklist](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheDevelopersQuittingYourJobTechnologyChecklist.aspx)

Comment: that DBAN tool you recommended ... that would wipe out my windows install as well, wouldn't it? this got me confused "... good way to totally clean a Microsoft Windows installation of viruses and spyware" ... they make it sounds like it doesn't wipe out your Windows install. Please let me know.

Comment: @rm - Yes. DBAN will remove absolutely everything from your hard drive. Try the Scott Hanselman article I linked to.

Comment: @jtbandes: posting a very quick, short answer so that you get the first answer in is a good way of getting a few upvotes in while you flesh out your answer. If you write something lengthy *before* posting, some turbo fingered little rep snatcher will inevitably beat you to it. **Realease early, release often** ;-)

Comment: @Charles: I understand the idea (hinted at in my comment about rep), though I've found that if you post a *better* answer, even if it's *slightly* late, you'll get more upvotes. Maybe I should try it and see. `:)`

Comment: @Qwerty: Sorry, i didn't see your comment. Thanks!

Comment: I second that link to Hanselman's blog: very nice checklist!

Answer (score 0):

Not to replace the job that CCleaner has, but you may also want to run [PC Decrapifier](http://pcdecrapifier.com/) as well. It is a tool that needs some more exposure (like CCleaner).

*"... good way to totally clean a Microsoft Windows installation of viruses and spyware"*

If you look at DBAN/formatting from a strict security point of view. Once your computer is infected it becomes compromised, you can no longer trust it. So it is a must to format. Simply cleaning the virus is no 100% indication that you are threat free.