# Utility to view how much space folders are taking in your hard disk?

Tags: windows-explorer, file-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best program to visualize file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/best-program-to-visualize-file-system-usage-on-windows)

Is there any free utility that will allow you to see how much space each folder is taking in your hard disk?

Comment: Duplicate of "Best program to visualize file system usage on Windows?" at http://superuser.com/questions/8248/best-program-to-visualize-file-system-usage-on-windows and "What’s using up my disk space?" at http://superuser.com/questions/22595/whats-using-up-my-disk-space

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may find the [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info) utility useful for this.  It's hosted on SourceForge.

> **Features**
>
> WinDirStat reads the whole directory
>   tree once and then presents it in
>   three useful views:
>
> - The directory list, which resembles the tree view of the Windows
>     Explorer but is sorted by file/subtree
>     size,
> - The treemap, which shows the whole contents of the directory tree
>     straight away,
> - The extension list, which serves as a legend and shows statistics about
>     the file types.

[image: Main window]

Comment: The program is localized for English and many other languages, even though the content of the screenshot shows a German installation of Windows.

Comment: this program ive used for decades.  but i can never remember what its called.  so luckily when i googled `windows utilities to get overview of all files on drive` this was the 5th link, and i saw the name, that was from this answer, in the results!  Awesome tool still!!!

Answer (score 3):

Personally I use TreeSize Free http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/

I have tried some other apps but this one is quick and has very little overhead, it's kind of a no-frills product.

JAM Software also have various pay versions with different features but I find the free version to be good enough for me.  Some of the other suggestions may be better for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Without a utility, right-clicking a folder and clicking properties will calculate the space it's taking up.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SequoiaView:](http://w3.win.tue.nl/nl/onderzoek/onderzoek_informatica/visualization/sequoiaview)

[image]

> Ever wondered why your hard disk is full? Or what directory is taking
>   up most of the space? When using conventional disk browsing tools,
>   such as Windows Explorer, these questions may be hard to answer. With
>   SequoiaView however, they can be answered almost immediately.
>   SequoiaView uses a visualization technique called cushion treemaps to
>   provide you with a single picture of the entire contents of your hard
>   drive. You can use it to locate those large files that you haven't
>   accessed in one year, or to quickly locate the largest picture files
>   on your drive.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I've been doing the same on other answers where I come across them.

Answer (score 0):

I used the [Zero Assumption disk space visualizer](http://www.z-a-recovery.com/tools-visualizer.htm). It worked pretty well and gave me a map with nested rectangles of different sizes representing the folders on the drive and their contents.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [overdisk](http://users.forthnet.gr/pat/efotinis/programs/overdisk.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use Folder Size Explorer Extension version 2.4 You can download it from Softpedia. It attaches itself to Windows Explorer. When you open Explorer it scans all your drives and gives you a complete breakdown of all folder sizes, down to individual files. I've used a dozen different programs looking for the right one. This one's perfect. If you don't like it, it's easy enough to uninstall.