# Finding out what directories are using the most space on windows

Tags: windows, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best program to visualize file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/best-program-to-visualize-file-system-usage-on-windows)

Hi, I have about 2 terabytes of total space spread over several drives.. While I still have 500 GB free which should last quite a while I want to do some cleanup.

I'm not very organized and the directory structure is a total mess.. It would take days to go through everything, but according to the 80/20 rule 80% of the space is used by 20% of directories. How do I find them?

For example:
C:\a - 200 GB
C:\b - 111 GB

Then if I want to see the subdirectories of C::
C:\a\b - 140 GB
C:\a\aaaa - 100 GB

..and so on.

Is there a builtin windows command / program or a 3rd party utility to do that?

Comment: Duplicate x3: http://superuser.com/questions/61036/utility-to-view-how-much-space-folders-are-taking-in-your-hard-disk http://superuser.com/questions/8248/best-program-to-visualize-file-system-usage-on-windows http://superuser.com/questions/22595/whats-using-up-my-disk-space

Comment: Quadruplicate, rather?

Comment: @JMD Triplicate, perhaps ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) was made for this task!

It'll show you exactly where your space is going.

Comment: I've used this in the past and it works well, even though the gradients look so '90s.

Comment: You can also use SequioaView ( http://w3.win.tue.nl/nl/onderzoek/onderzoek_informatica/visualization/sequoiaview/ )

Comment: The gradients are... functional. I guess.

Answer (score 9):

[TreeSize](http://www.jam-software.com/freeware/index.shtml) is another such application.

[image: Treesize in action]

Comment: You beat me to it by 52 seconds.  I've deleted mine and +1'd yours.

Comment: I'd like to add that this looks a little safer than WinDirStat from a security perspective. I haven't looked at the code, though. But WindDirStat has to be downloaded from one of a few shady looking sites. This is downloaded right from the developers website.

Answer (score 7):

I like [SpaceSniffer](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/index.html). Small, fast, and doesn't require an install.

Comment: +1 for posting at same time as me, and remembering to mention the zero install. This is another one to stick on a USB key full of tools

Answer (score 4):

Fans of the mighty **[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/)** use the **[VisualDirSize](http://www.totalcmd.net/plugring/visdirsize.html)** plug-in.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**I like [SpaceMonger](http://www.sixty-five.cc/sm/)**.

No assumption graphical interface,
The older version is free. Rightclick gives menu items 'delete','open', 'zoom', etc...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

And another one: [Overdisk](http://users.forthnet.gr/pat/efotinis/programs/overdisk.html)

Answer (score 1):

I used to use Sequoia but started to find the look a bit dated, and it was flaky (especially if cancelled).
Now prefer [Spacesniffer](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/index.html), really intuitive to zoom in an a folder, zoom in again and so on, and be able to use back button to zoom back out to previous screen. Seems fairly quick too.

Answer (score 0):

For viewing disk usage I prefer Steffen Gerlach's [Scanner](http://www.steffengerlach.de/freeware/), for its innovative and visual pie display, and where each pie can be accessed by using click drilling and right-click menu.

[image]

Comment: Pies and their stranger derivatives are horrible ways to compare chunks of data. I can't tell which purple wedge is larger for example

Comment: You can by passing the cursor over it - it's indicated up left. Pies are the most visual for me, at least.