# What's a good tool to find where my hard drive space is being used?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best program to visualize file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/best-program-to-visualize-file-system-usage-on-windows)

I am looking for a tool that will tell me where my hard drive space is being used.

I used to use one called Scanner.exe (I think that was the name) that was written in Delphi.  But I have lost it and can't find it again.

Does any one know of a good free windows tool that tells you were your hard drive space is being used.  (Aside from selecting properties on a bunch of folders.)

Comment: Dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/8248/best-program-to-visualize-file-system-usage-on-windows

Comment: And here: http://superuser.com/questions/70246/finding-out-what-directories-are-using-the-most-space-on-windows-closed

Comment: and http://superuser.com/questions/22595/whats-using-up-my-disk-space

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) is rather nice.  You can mouseover the boxed area and specifics are shown on the status bar at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: gotta post it quick before molly does...

Comment: The absolute best!

Comment: 85+ rep for an answer that you pulled from a post that you added here as 'dupe'.  haha

Comment: eh, i pulled it from a post a while ago.  been using it recently, so it was already at my fingertips.  but this isn't nearly as ridiculous as the toner question the other day...

Answer (score 3):

One which has not been listed yet in this question or any of the others listed in the comments:

**[SpaceSniffer](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/index.html)**: *dynamic* vizualization of your disk space
(i.e. when you remove some large directories, you will see the occupied space of the disk re-organized accordingly)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**[SpaceMonger](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/spacemonger.html)** is a tool for keeping track of the free space on your computer. Each file or folder on a given drive is displayed in a box in the main window whose size is a relative comparison to all the other files in your system. The program supports popup info-tips that can display the full filename, the icon, the date, size, and attributes of any file or folder. You can delete files from the right click menu and customize the number of files to be shown as well as the color scheme.

[image]

Of course, if you're using Total Commander, you can always grab the free **[VisualDirSize](http://www.totalcmd.net/plugring/visdirsize.html)** plugin:

[image]

[image]