# Windows 7 - missing free HDD space

Tags: windows-7, disk-space

I have Windows 7 installed on a 45 GB partition, and every now and then it gets full, and I have to resize that partition. I always thought this was quite normal. But it happened again today and this time, I'm sure it is not normal, because since last resizing (35GB -> 45GB) I did not install any new apps or anything and the sum of the folder sizes is off. 
Everything, including hidden, system, root folders and files is ~18GB, yet Windows is indicating that all 45 GB are used up.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to see what is taking disk space with a tool like [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/).

[image]

It will show you how the space is used, and by what, so you will be able to understand and take measures according to this. Don't hesitate to edit your question with what exactly is taking more space, if you want more details about it.

Comment: Great program, using it for years. Just before deleting that huge file Google it

Comment: I recently found out, you should run WinDirStat (or similar pieces of software) as Administrator in order for the program to correctly find and sum up all files/dirs (especially files in the Windows-folder, that are otherwise skipped). Simply right-click executable and select "Run as administrator"

Answer (score 4):

I like better [Scanner](http://www.steffengerlach.de/freeware/) for its useful pie design and right-click context menu:

[image]

Comment: Would the down-voter please explain why? Scanner is a program I like and use a lot.

Comment: People downvote easily without reason, obviously.. I have to say I prefer pie design for exploring disk, I was a big fan of diskSpace Explorer, but the company making it is now caring about something else, unfortunately.. OverDisk is not bad too as a pie design, and keeps the tree as well: http://users.forthnet.gr/pat/efotinis/programs/overdisk.html

Answer (score 2):

Another useful program in the fight against storage space, is "SpaceSniffer" (http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/index.html).   Tested on Windows 2000, XP, Vista, and 7.  Also freeware.

This program works great and quite fast (as fast as the machine can handle).   Simple hover the mouse cursor over a data block or click for more information.   There is even a tip on the author's website to integrate SpaceSniffer into the Windows Explorer Context Menu.  Handy!

Check out the website, I'm new here and cannot post a picture.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/22595/whats-using-up-my-disk-space).  In my case, it was the shadow copy system using up more than 50% of my hard drive.  The accepted answer solved the problem for me, and you can use the vssadmin to set a maximum amount of space to use.

Comment: Thank you, but I've already found a solution, see second Edit.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it!  Perhaps someone else who finds this question will be helped by my mention of shadow-copy.  Maybe not.  :)  Have a good one.

Answer (score 0):

in windows 8.1 my **windows.edb** was 99 gb on a 256 gb drive. it has to index my 250k onedrive files for it to function

[image: large windows.edb]