# How to determine where my disk space went

Tags: windows, disk-space

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to find disk usage of folders in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/10820/how-to-find-disk-usage-of-folders-in-windows)
>   [Best program to visualize file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/best-program-to-visualize-file-system-usage-on-windows)
>   [What’s using up my disk space?](https://superuser.com/questions/22595/whats-using-up-my-disk-space)
>   [Windows 7 - mysteriously missing free HDD space](https://superuser.com/questions/61880/windows-7-mysteriously-missing-free-hdd-space/)

C: is getting really really low. :P

I used to use a program from moleskinsoft.com to do this task (it has since expired), but I need a nice free application that looks at one of my drives and tells me how big each folder is and where all my space has gone.

Comment: superuser.com is probably a better place for this.

Answer (score 10):

SpaceMonger isn't bad (referring to Barden's suggestion), but I also like [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/). It's OpenSource. I even use it on my servers. It can scan network drives too and gives a nice graphical output that shows files as multicolored blocks. Take a look at the site for screenshots.

Comment: @DigitalRoss: Indeed it does. I just wish it wasn't a dormant project. =(

Comment: So I downloaded it and yes, it actually rocks :-)

Answer (score 3):

[TreeSize Free](http://www.jam-software.com/freeware/index.shtml) works well. They have paid Personal and Pro versions, too.

Answer (score 1):

Eversince SpaceMonger went paid, I went with [SpaceSniffer](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/index.html). It does the same type of analysis and visualisation.

Answer (score 0):

I still like the free version of spacemonger. I'm sure the new one is great but the freeware one does the trick for us:

http://www.sixty-five.cc/sm/v1x.php

It's graphical so its easy to spot big files and you can open directories from it's inteface. I haven't had any problem running it from x64 or x86 windows.

Answer (score 0):

I use [SequoiaView](http://w3.win.tue.nl/nl/onderzoek/onderzoek_informatica/visualization/sequoiaview//) for Windows machine. The fastest among free ones. and its GUI is easy to see.