# Disk Used Space Anamoly viz Actual Space Used by Files

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, disk-space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 - mysteriously missing free HDD space](https://superuser.com/questions/61880/windows-7-mysteriously-missing-free-hdd-space)

I just got my Laptop and was transferring the content from my Previous Laptop. My Current Laptop has about 326 GB in C:. Today morning to my surprise I saw, the current Used Space is 318 GB. As I usually do, I tried to figure out the total space my files and directories were taking to ascertain who is eating up my space. To my surprise, I see a huge difference in what was claimed to be the Used Space and the size of the Total Files present in the drive. The Total File Size includes the size of the hidden files and folder.

Note in case it matters, my current fragmentation is just 4%

I am puzzled ....

[image]

Comment: I suggest running [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) for insight on hard drive usage.

Comment: @MarcusChan: Thanks, using this Tool helped me to identify the problem

Comment: I prefer TreeSizeFree, run it with admin and it will show you the space of protected folder like `C:\System Volume Information`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MarcusChan, where by his suggested WinDirStat, which instantly helped me to identify the problem. I am running Windows 7, and some of the folders seems to be protected and would require elevation through UAC to view the content. When I was checking the file spaces through explorer, it was wrongly reporting as it was not considering the spaces for these folders was eating up the space.

Using WinDirStat made the picture clearer and then it was obvious that running Explorer as an Administrator would have actually reported the right information.