# Installed SSD, Windows says it's half full

Tags: windows-7, ssd

So I just installed Windows 7 on my new 120GB Samsung SSD, everything has been working fine, except...

In "Computer", where all the drives are displayed, my boot drive (the SSD) says that "60.0 GB" is used space, seen below.

[image]

But when going into the actual drive, enabling the viewing of hidden files, and selecting everything there, it totals up to only 36.6 GB!

[image]

I disabled the pagefile for this drive, turned off hibernation, and the recycle bin is only about 5GB or so...

Any idea where my missing 23.4 GB are? Thanks!

By the way, the Users folder in my C drive (SSD) is actually a symlink to my data hard drive. The Users folder is about 10GB, so exactly 26.6 GB is actually being used on the drive.

Comment: Why you'd want to put the pagefile on a slower drive escapes me. The whole point of an SSD is quick access to the most frequently accessed data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 - missing free HDD space](http://superuser.com/questions/61880/windows-7-missing-free-hdd-space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually didn't enable all of the files. You should also unselect the box "Hide protected operating system files".

Whenever I wonder where my disk space has gone, I use WinDirStat (on Windows) or kdirstat (the original, and for Linux):
https://windirstat.info/

What this program does is find all of the files and display which folders/files are using up all the space. It's easy to drill down and find out massive nuggets of wasted space!

[image]

Comment: It seems the 20GB pagefile I disabled still stuck around, so I'm going to decrease it and reboot, thanks!

Comment: @TrivisionZero after disabling it you can just delete the page file manually.