# Recycle bin has subfolder with 2GB of files that I cannot delete

Tags: windows-7, recycle-bin

Windows 7

I run TreeSize on my c:\ drive and it reports that my Recycle bin has 2GB of files in it (in a subfolder).

My desktop recycle bin icon shows that my bin is empty.  I even try creating a test file, deleting it, which then shows in the recycle bin and then I rt click and empty the bin.  Treesize still reports the subfolder and 2GB worth of files.

The sub folder is:

```
c:\$recycle.bin\S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxx
```

I've tried opening a command line as admin and doing a `dir *.* /ah` on those files, which works.  But when I try to delete any of those files, it says access denied.  I've tried `takeown /F *.*` on those files and deleting and it still says access denied.

Any ideas on how to get rid of those files taking up so much space?

Comment: Try using Unlocker

Comment: A related question with good answers is here: http://superuser.com/questions/125640/windows-7-shows-a-drive-as-full-in-summary-but-files-shown-on-drive-are-very-smal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) worked to remove the files that I was not able to delete