# Find out where Data is stored in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, filesystems, storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s using up my disk space?](https://superuser.com/questions/22595/whats-using-up-my-disk-space)
>   [Best program to visualize file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/best-program-to-visualize-file-system-usage-on-windows)

I've recently hit the cap on my 450gig HD and I can't seem to figure out where all that data went.

Is there some tool that allows me to see where in my file system all the data is being stored?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the question and answers here: [What's using up my disk space?](https://superuser.com/questions/22595/whats-using-up-my-disk-space)

Also, check out the tools in this question: [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/best-program-to-visualize-file-system-usage-on-windows)

These will allow you to analyze your disk.

I don't think this is a duplicate question, because the answer could be anything at this point.

Comment: it's really kind of a duplicate of both.

Comment: @quack - yea, wasn't sure how to handle this one... kind of a duplicate but much more general