# Hard Disk is full but not due to files

Tags: hard-drive, disk-space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's using up my disk space?](https://superuser.com/questions/22595/whats-using-up-my-disk-space)

Hello!
I have a 40 GB hard drive which is full in explorer (10 MB remaining). The drive is NTFS running Windows 7.

In Explorer, I go to Tools > Folder Options
I select 'show hidden files and folders' 
I unselect all options which start with 'Hide'

In Explorer, I select all.
View properties.
The 'size of files on disk' is 14 GB.

So how is my 40 GB drive full? Looking for investigation vectors and recommendations.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a possible duplicate of [What's using up my disk space?](http://superuser.com/questions/22595/whats-using-up-my-disk-space) - you might what to have a read of the suggestions there. Hidden *system* files was going to be my first suggestion.

Comment: Bare in mind unhiding, selecting and checking the size of everything visible is *not* accurate - it will not see files you don't have permissions for (which should be all of the System Vol folder, for example, and maybe others).

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use something like [TreeSize Free](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) to figure out where your disk space is being consumed.

Comment: Another tool which does a similar function is [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/), I like this one because it's a single executable with no dependencies.