# can I delete the files in /windows/installer?

Tags: windows, cleaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it safe to delete from C:\Windows\Installer?](https://superuser.com/questions/23479/is-it-safe-to-delete-from-c-windows-installer)

Is the /windows/installer folder for files used during installation, and were not deleted for some reason?

Can I delete them?

(windows xp laptop)

Comment: dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/23479/is-it-safe-to-delete-from-c-windows-installer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows needs those files if you want to Uninstall your programs later.

While you can delete them and your program will still work, the Uninstall/Reinstall options from Add/Remove programs will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. 
This article may help. You will need a Microsoft utility to do so. As I understand. And, ideologically, programs, when installed, may recreate this directory. 
http://www.techspot.com/vb/topic109060.html