# Can I delete the files in C:\Windows\Installer folder?

Tags: windows-xp, disk-space, windows-installer, installer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it safe to delete from C:\Windows\Installer?](https://superuser.com/questions/23479/is-it-safe-to-delete-from-c-windows-installer)

The folder "C:\Windows\Installer" on my **Windows XP** contains 2 GiB of .msi files. I know they are Windows Installer cache files. But is it safe to delete them? They're eating my hard drive space. Does deleting them cause problems for the uninstallation of the programs?

I also noticed none of the registry entries in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall points to them.