# Windows/Installer and Windows/winsxs using up 25% of my 60gb SSD

Tags: windows-7, windows, ssd

I'm wondering if anyone knows a safe way to clean these two folders or even clean the Windows folder so that I can get some space back as it's eating 25% of my SSD, the entire windows folder is taking 30%

[image: http://i.imgur.com/1QQNRZ8.png]

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the /winsxs folder grow so large, and can it be made smaller?](http://superuser.com/questions/1/why-does-the-winsxs-folder-grow-so-large-and-can-it-be-made-smaller), [Is it safe to delete from C:\Windows\Installer?](http://superuser.com/questions/23479/is-it-safe-to-delete-from-c-windows-installer)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I've already tried those, the first one does nothing for me and the second doesn't help :/

Comment: Doesn't make it different questions. If you'd like newer/better answers for the existing questions please feel free to post a bounty on the one(s) you'd like them for.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the [update KB2852386](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2852386) on Windows 7, open disk cleanup here you can cleanup WinSxS a bit.

[image: WindowsUpdateCleanup]

The folder `C:\Windows\Installer` includes the Microsoft Installer (MSI) files and patches, so that you don't need to point to the sources if you change features of installed programs or try to remove it. [This folder can't be cleaned](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/01/18/can-you-safely-delete-files-in-the-windir-installer-directory.aspx), except by removing programs which you don't need.