# Windows 11 Installer got deleted

Tags: windows-11, windows-installation

for some reason I'm accidentally delete C:/Windows/Installer folder on Windows 11 and don't have a system restore point, I've already tried reset this PC with keep data enabled and it doesn't seems to fix the issue and windows security going blank, what do I need to do? Do I need to totally reset the PC without keeping the data?

Comment: First try downloading the Windows 11 ISO, https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11, and put it on USB, using Create Windows 11 Installation Media. Then try reinstalling from USB, **keeping all files**, which *should* preserve data and apps. To be safe, I'd make a disk image first, lest something go wrong...

Comment: @DrMoishePippik is it really need to use a usb? because my usb quite questionable

Comment: c:/Windows/Installer isn’t used by Windows, anything in that folder, can be regenerated eventually by Windows. [Its a cache folder](https://superuser.com/questions/23479/is-it-safe-to-delete-from-c-windows-installer), it’s needed, but not the end of the world.

Comment: @Ramhound but some reason I get a few issue like, C++ 2008 won't update then I reset the PC with data keep and then the windows defender completely won't work, it's blank, scanning show page isn't available pop up

Comment: @RickyNolep - C++ 2008 hasn’t been supported for 10 years. So there are no updates in 2024. Windows Defender being blank is not likely related

Comment: @Ramhound for some reason windows updater prompt it tho, it does fixed for now but what about the defender? Im afraid that my PC is in vulnerable state

Comment: You haven’t provided any information about that particular problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150872/discussion-between-ricky-nolep-and-ramhound).

Comment: Maybe you should use recovery software tools, to recover the target folder.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub don't think that's possible anymore its too long since the time I deleted it, the damage has been done, I don't mind loosing data tho just want to get it fixed