# Can I delete files from C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download?

Tags: windows-xp, disk-space

I need to free space on Windows XP SP3.

Q1) What system folders can be safely delete in case I don't need to have restore points etc?

Q2) Can I delete content from `C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download`

Comment: Why didn't it find this question when I was creating mine? http://superuser.com/questions/53266/safe-to-delete-c-windows-softwaredistribution-download

Comment: I already deleted all content from 'the directory'. Rebooted the computer and everything looks ok. Updates were turned off for ages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Q1: That’s a complex and messy question. If you just want to strip XP down to the [minimal](http://www.google.com/search?q=minimal%20xp) size, your best bet is to look at what others have done. [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/) is a great resource for this.

Q2: Yes, assuming that you have not recently installed any Windows Updates (or made sure to reboot afterwards), then [it is safe](https://superuser.com/questions/53266/safe-to-delete-c-windows-softwaredistribution-download) to delete `SoftwareDistribution\Download`.

Comment: Q1) can I use nLite for an existing installation?

Comment: No, but you can use the list of folder that are removed in order to determine what to delete. However, be wary that if it is already installed, it may not be as simple as just deleting a folder (there may be references to it in the registry or other files). Depending on what it is, you may need to uninstall stuff (eg Windows Components in Add/Remove Programs) to be safe. [MSFN](http://www.msfn.org) is also a good place to find advice on what is safe. (I recall seeing a discreet list a while back; I’ll post a link if I can find it again.)

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer:** I'm using Windows 7.

Personally, I wouldn't be touching any system folders.  Some tips to free space:

1. From *My Computer*, right-click the hard drive and select *Properties* and press *Disk Cleanup*.  I recommend selecting all options except "Downloaded Program Files".
2. In C:\ delete any folders that are just a string of hex-digits.  These are old installers.
3. In C:\ delete all files.  Any files that were there were from old installers.  **Note: may not be the case in Windows XP.**
4. Clean out your documents and media files.  Are you ever really going to open that file again?  Move your media to a secondary or external drive.

Quite frankly, if you're that tight for disk space it's time to invest in a new drive.

Comment: It’s not always about disk space.

Comment: @Synetech, what do you mean?  The question states "I need to free space".

Comment: True. But some people like to strip down Windows regardless of available space. `;-)`