# Missing WinPE Packages to Install KB4346783?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, wpf

I'm attempting to install KB4346783 (like: [Can't install Windows 10 update (KB4346783)](https://superuser.com/questions/1355912/cant-install-windows-10-update-kb4346783))

I followed all the steps in the comments (removing the folder in software/distribution/, fiddling with DISM etc) and I will dump my CBS log.

My current OS version is 1803:17134.319 (I tried installing this update on LTSB Enterprise 1607, failed) and I understand that I'm missing some dependencies (by the `parent state: absent`), although googling gives no results (just tutorials on WinPE).

It's pretty important that I can (hopefully) deploy this patch as it *should* fix some issues I'm having with WPF touch elements.

```
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    TI: --- Initializing Trusted Installer ---
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    TI: Last boot time: 2018-09-21 14:23:09.500
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    Starting TrustedInstaller initialization.
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    Lock: New lock added: CCbsPublicSessionClassFactory, level: 30, total lock:4
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    Lock: New lock added: CCbsPublicSessionClassFactory, level: 30, total lock:5
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    Lock: New lock added: WinlogonNotifyLock, level: 8, total lock:6
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    Ending TrustedInstaller initialization.
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    Starting the TrustedInstaller main loop.
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    TrustedInstaller service starts successfully.
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    No startup processing required, TrustedInstaller service was not set as autostart
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    Startup processing thread terminated normally
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    TI: Startup Processing completes, release startup processing lock.
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    WU creates the package, AppID:wusa, UpdateID:{6D03D892-32D0-4BA9-AB83-A257D394F676}, revision: 501
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    Starting TiWorker initialization.
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    Lock: New lock added: TiWorkerClassFactory, level: 30, total lock:2
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    Ending TiWorker initialization.
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    Starting the TiWorker main loop.
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    TiWorker starts successfully.
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    Lock: New lock added: CCbsWorker, level: 5, total lock:3
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    Universal Time is: 2018-09-21 13:51:31.671
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    Loaded Servicing Stack v10.0.17134.281 with Core: C:\WINDOWS\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.281_none_eada712a1d8142be\cbscore.dll
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    Build: 17134.1.amd64fre.rs4_release.180410-1804
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CSI    00000001@2018/9/21:13:51:31.671 WcpInitialize (wcp.dll version 0.0.0.6) called (stack @0x7ffa5a26c2b9 @0x7ffa5aab2a06 @0x7ffa5aacdf1f @0x7ff71f862c32 @0x7ff71f8635e8 @0x7ffa844a46f3)
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    Lock: New lock added: CCbsSessionManager, level: 11, total lock:8
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    Lock: New lock added: CSIInventoryCriticalSection, level: 64, total lock:9
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    NonStart: Set pending store consistency check.
2018-09-21 14:51:31, Info                  CBS    Session: 30691762_870095838 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent, external staging directory: (null), external registry directory: (null
2018-09-21 14:51:32, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~17134.254.1.2, Parent: Microsoft-Windows-CoreCountrySpecificEdition~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17134.1, Disposition = Detect, VersionComp: EQ, BuildComp: EQ, RevisionComp: EQ, Exist: present
2018-09-21 14:51:32, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent (exact match): Parent: Microsoft-Windows-CoreCountrySpecificEdition~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17134.1, parent state: Absent
2018-09-21 14:51:32, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~17134.254.1.2, Parent: Microsoft-Windows-CoreEdition~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17134.1, Disposition = Detect, VersionComp: EQ, BuildComp: EQ, RevisionComp: EQ, Exist: present
2018-09-21 14:51:32, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent (exact match): Parent: Microsoft-Windows-CoreEdition~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17134.1, parent state: Absent
2018-09-21 14:51:32, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~17134.254.1.2, Parent: Microsoft-Windows-CoreNEdition~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17134.1, Disposition = Detect, VersionComp: EQ, BuildComp: EQ, RevisionComp: EQ, Exist: present
2018-09-21 14:51:32, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent (exact match): Parent: Microsoft-Windows-CoreNEdition~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17134.1, parent state: Absent
2018-09-21 14:51:32, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~17134.254.1.2, Parent: Microsoft-Windows-EnterpriseEvalEdition~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17134.1, Disposition = Detect, VersionComp: EQ, BuildComp: EQ, RevisionComp: EQ, Exist: present
2018-09-21 14:51:32, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent (exact match): Parent: Microsoft-Windows-EnterpriseEvalEdition~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17134.1, parent state: Absent
2018-09-21 14:51:32, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~17134.254.1.2, Parent: Microsoft-Windows-EnterpriseGEdition~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17134.1, Disposition = Detect, VersionComp: EQ, BuildComp: EQ, RevisionComp: EQ, Exist: present
2018-09-21 14:51:32, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent (exact match): Parent: Microsoft-Windows-EnterpriseGEdition~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17134.1, parent state: Absent
2018-09-21 14:51:32, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~17134.254.1.2, Parent: Microsoft-Windows-EnterpriseNEvalEdition~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17134.1, Disposition = Detect, VersionComp: EQ, BuildComp: EQ, RevisionComp: EQ, Exist: present
2018-09-21 14:51:32, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent (exact match): Parent: Microsoft-Windows-EnterpriseNEvalEdition~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17134.1, parent state: Absent
2018-09-21 14:51:32, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~17134.254.1.2, Parent: Microsoft-Windows-ProfessionalEdition~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17134.1, Disposition = Detect, VersionComp: EQ, BuildComp: EQ, RevisionComp: EQ, Exist: present
2018-09-21 14:51:32, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent (exact match): Parent: Microsoft-Windows-ProfessionalEdition~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17134.1, parent state: Absent
2018-09-21 14:51:32, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~17134.254.1.2, Parent: Microsoft-Windows-ProfessionalNEdition~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17134.1, Disposition = Detect, VersionComp: EQ, BuildComp: EQ, RevisionComp: EQ, Exist: present
2018-09-21 14:51:32, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent (exact match): Parent: Microsoft-Windows-ProfessionalNEdition~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17134.1, parent state: Installed
2018-09-21 14:51:32, Info                  CBS    Appl: Higher version found for package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~17134.254.1.2, superseded. (Version on system:Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~17134.319.1.10)
2018-09-21 14:51:32, Info                  CBS    Appl: Evaluating package applicability for package Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~17134.254.1.2, applicable state: Superseded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your system indicates that a newer version of the package is already installed:

```
2018-09-21 14:51:32, Info                  CBS    Appl: Higher version found for package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~17134.254.1.2, superseded. (Version on system:Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~17134.319.1.10)
2018-09-21 14:51:32, Info                  CBS    Appl: Evaluating package applicability for package Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~17134.254.1.2, applicable state: Superseded
```

You're trying to install the [August 2018 Cumulative Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4346783). Your system indicates you already have the [September 2018 Cumulative Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4458469) installed. Because, all cumulative updates are, well, cumulative, [they include any fixes that would've been released previously](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/824684/description-of-the-standard-terminology-that-is-used-to-describe-micro) in the August update.

If you'd like to confirm you do, in fact, have the September 20th cumulative update installed, you can check for it in your Windows Update History. To do so:

- Click the Start Button then the Gear icon for the Settings App.
- Choose Update & Security then make sure that Windows Update is selected on the left hand side.
- Click on View Installed Update History to see any recently installed updates and confirm that KB4458469 is already installed.

Comment: The author doesn’t have to confirm this is the case, I can confirm it’s the case, the patch is 17134.254 which was released on August 30th I believe, but the author indicated they have 17134.319 which was released this week on Tuesday

Comment: Thank you. I can't currently check as I do not have access to the machine, but this does indeed seem likely (I had a small inclination as the version I had was more recent). I will mark it as an answer when I can verify it on Monday.