# Windows updates + delete c:\windows\SoftwareDistribution

Tags: windows

Have a quick hypothetical question, If I have a pending Windows(10) update and was to delete the contents of c:\windows\SoftwareDistribution folder would that prevent  windows from installing the update? (Im assuming it will have to re-download the the update package and if a user was to keep deleting the contents of c:\windows\SoftwareDistribution folder they can prevent the update from ever installing).
Thank you for any feedback.

Comment: Possibly... but files can be loaded from another PC on the network, depending on settings.

Comment: hmmm, thats right, i recently saw something about the fact that windows gets its updates from other user's PC's, is that something recent they introduced?

Comment: here is the thread that mentioned this btw: https://twitter.com/GossiTheDog/status/1152935306619949056

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safe to delete "C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download"](https://superuser.com/questions/53266/safe-to-delete-c-windows-softwaredistribution-download)