# How manually clean up C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download?

Tags: windows-10

What  https://superuser.com/a/53274/269574 mean? I uneducated in computer. Look below. No idea what mean all these letter number combinations. No idea delete what!

> After you have installed all the pending updates, it is safe to delete
>   all the files and folder under
>   C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\
>
> As [@Zab said,](https://superuser.com/questions/53266/safe-to-delete-c-windows-softwaredistribution-download/386242#386242) stop the Update Service while you clean up the
>   folder.
>
> 1. Enter `net stop wuauserv` into an elevated command prompt
> 2. Manually clean up `C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download`
> 3. Enter `net start wuauserv` into an elevated command prompt    As soon as the service starts again, some folders will be re-created.
>      This is ok.

[image]

Comment: Press WinKey + R and type `cleanmgr c:`. You can choose in the program to clean up as user or clean up system as admin.

Answer (score 5):

What your linked answer means by "clean up" is to delete **all** of them. In other words delete the download folder.

Here is the proper way to reset Windows updates from the Command Prompt, each of the lines below has to be run one at a time, after typing each one hit enter key then type the next command. **Spaces are important in these commands**.

Command prompt can be found in the All Programs-Accessories folder on the start menu, right click on Command prompt icon and select run as administrator.

> net stop wuauserv
>
> rmdir %windir%\softwaredistribution /s /q
>
> rmdir %windir%\system32\softwaredistribution /s /q
>
> regsvr32 /s wuaueng.dll
>
> regsvr32 /s wuaueng1.dll
>
> regsvr32 /s atl.dll
>
> regsvr32 /s wups.dll
>
> regsvr32 /s wups2.dll
>
> regsvr32 /s wuweb.dll
>
> regsvr32 /s wucltui.dll
>
> net start wuauserv