# Free program to delete old unused files in Windows

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, disk-space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows registry and system cleaner applications ?](https://superuser.com/questions/6668/windows-registry-and-system-cleaner-applications)

My drive c is becoming very very low on disc space, and I need to reguarly delete and cleanup files both in the temporary folders in the User and Application Data.

Is there a free program out there that can find these cache folders and other old and unused folders so that I can get some free space on my drive c in windows 7?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows registry and system cleaner applications?](http://superuser.com/questions/6668/windows-registry-and-system-cleaner-applications) and/or [Reclaiming disk space on Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/8141/reclaiming-disk-space-on-windows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER) is a popular free "cleaner" app.

From the website

> CCleaner is our system optimization,
>   privacy and cleaning tool. It removes
>   unused files from your system -
>   allowing Windows to run faster and
>   freeing up valuable hard disk space.
>   It also cleans traces of your online
>   activities such as your Internet
>   history. Additionally it contains a
>   fully featured registry cleaner. But
>   the best part is that it's fast
>   (normally taking less than a second to
>   run) and contains NO Spyware or
>   Adware!

Full features list [here](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/features).