# Windows 8 just keep eating all the space on C: drive

Tags: windows-8, disk-space

Here is what I see. I'm running W8 as VM and did expand drive couple times. I just work on this PC(software development) and it's constantly rising. There is also no connection between "all files" space and what "My computer" showing.

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear.  This question still applies http://superuser.com/questions/8141/reclaiming-disk-space-on-windows?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Selecting all files and showing properties skips files where don't have access to. Run [TreesizeFree](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) ([as admin](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token)) and look which folders eat most space.

[image]

Now delete or move data that you don't need on drive C:\